# db_ddladmin role, can not create DDL trigger

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I working in shared host.

**#1**
my user (fitapptk_usr) has db_ddladmin role.
[image: see image]

**#2**
at this address we see that db_ddladmin role has ALTER ANY DATABASE DDL TRIGGER
[Database-Level Roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/database-level-roles?view=sql-server-2017)
[image]

**#3**
Microsoft in this article says:
[(link)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/enable-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#permissions)

> To enable a DDL trigger with database scope (ON DATABASE), at a
>   minimum, a user must have ALTER ANY DATABASE DDL TRIGGER permission in
>   the current database.

**To pay attention to #1, #2 and #3 I should be able to create a DDL Trigger but when I use this code**

```
CREATE TRIGGER SAFETY   
ON database
FOR DROP_TABLE, ALTER_TABLE   
AS   
   PRINT 'MESSAGE: TRIGGER " SAFETY " PREVENT TO DO THIS'   
   ROLLBACK;
```

**I receive this error:**

> Cannot create the trigger 'SAFETY', because you do not have
>   permission.

Comment: A quick test on my Sandbox server, and the `db_ddladmin` role works for creating a database trigger. This strongly infers that you have a different role/permission that is an explicit `DENY` in regards to DDL triggers, or another required permission. `DENY` > `GRANT`.